# How to exclude one item from an array based on another array's condition (for deck of playing cards)?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, playing-cards

I have two arrays one for the card suit `suit_list = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]` and one for the values `value_list = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]`

I have written the code to select a card at random.

Based on this, for the random card selected e.g. 2 of Diamonds, I would like to **prevent** from being selected again.

How can I tackle this approach? My initial thought was to use a conditional approach in nested for loops but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would make an array of all 52 cards (maybe a tuple, ex: `("A", "Hearts")`) then randomly remove cards as needed. Kind of like a real deck of cards.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.  In particular, "How do I implement this feature?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than thinking of removing a card from play, why not create the deck, shuffle it, then as you need cards from the deck just take the next card from the array.

```
import random
import itertools

suit_list = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
value_list = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]

deck = list(itertools.product(suit_list, value_list))
random.shuffle(deck)

for card in deck:
    print(card)
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked a treat, added some additional functions to remove the card from the list every time it is shuffled. Cheers!